# How to filter datagridview column

Tags: vb.net, select, datagridview

For example I have a datagridview1 with data imported from a text file and there are 3 columns: ID, Name, Gender.

What I want to do is to select/show only all with the Male in Gender column.

I dont have any database here so I can't use sql queries or is there a way to manipulate datagridview using sql queries? Just like this:

```
SELECT * FROM DataGridView1 WHERE Gender='Male'
```

Any response would really be appreciated.

Comment: 1) Google DataTable, DataView 2) Read the data into a DataTable 3) Create a DataView based on the DataTable (or use the default view of the table) 4) Set the `RowFilter` property of the DataView to `Gender='Male'` 5) Set the `DataSource` property of the DGV to the DataView instance (or the table if you're using the default view).

Comment: Thanks @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, but can you show me that in codes?

Comment: When you imported the text, did you simply add it to the DGV or is the data stored in something like a List or DataTable?

Comment: hi @Plutonix, yes it is just in the DGV. please help me

Answer (score 0):

I am C# developer, don't know if there are any built in functions in VB to do this, but the simplest way I think would be to just loop through datagridview and filter manually, you can then either remove that row or make in invisible.

You can implement basic search this way too. Of course this is not the fastest nor the most effective way to do it, but it will get the job done. Alternatively you can store all data in a list or an array to make the loop run faster. Also to improve performance you can hide datagrid when loop is started and show it again when loop is finished, that way system won't waste time on showing datagrid animations.

For example you you have a number column and you want to show rows that have values between 50-100, simple code will look something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<datagridview1.rows.count; i++)
{
   int t = Convert.toint32(datagridview.rows[i].cells[0].value);
   if(t<50 || t>100) datagridview.rows[i].visible = false;
   else datagridview.rows[i].visible = true;
}
```

Code is in C# and will need some spellchecking but I think you got the idea.
I hope I was able to help. Cheers.

Comment: thank you and i got the idea but it's not the way it can be solved.

Comment: You are welcome, but why not? It is a fairly simple thing to implement, anyway, good luck.

Comment: I think i would have issues regarding data types. can you provide another example with String which will be used in filtering. again, thank you for your help.

Comment: Fairly simple. Again not the fastest way, but should get the job done. You can either compare string using = or you can use String.Contains() method to see if one string contains the other. Beware of capital or lower case letter, you can make both string low letter or use overloads to ignore that. Just google C# string comparison.